# How can I change tomboy note's background colour?

Tags: themes, tomboy, colors, preferences

How to make Tomboy Notes have a different theme that are easier on the eyes like black font over a lightgrey background rather than a darkgrey font over a white background. I have explored Tomboy's preference window, toyed a bit with gnome "appearance" settings, and even tried to tweak the Gtk+ code but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like in my desktop setting, I need to restart my X session for widget colours settings could be applied. I could use the `$GTK2_RC_FILES` environment variable to define the colours profile only for one program, rather than overall.

Second, the text colours (highlight, titles, links, ...) are defined in NoteTag.cs file in the Tomboy sources (`InitCommonTags()` method). It's not possible to run the rebuilt Tomboy.exe file directly, though: you need to proceed to a "sudo make install" (in /usr/local) first to have all the libraries and resources moved to their expected location.

e.g. use foreground-yellow instead of background-yellow on highlight

```
tag = new NoteTag ("highlight");
// tag.Background = "yellow"; // commented out
tag.PaletteForeground = ContrastPaletteColor.Yellow; // <- inserted
tag.CanUndo = true;
tag.CanGrow = true;
tag.CanSpellCheck = true;
Add (tag);
```

Have fun.